# Can I increase the character count of the Label of form fields?

Tags: sitecore-forms

In Sitecore 9, I'm constructing some forms using the form builder. When I add Single-line and Multiple-line fields, there seems to be a 256-character limit on the Label of those form elements. When you enter a stsring longer than that, it cuts it off.

Is there a way to override/increase this without utilizing a custom field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the label from the `Content Editor` for this. If you are using `Form Designer` it will cut off the text. but if you will use the `Content Editor` for this it will work fine, because the `Title` field is `single-line` text field in Sitecore. All you need to navigate the field for which you want to update the label and then select the `Title` field, add your text and save the field- 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mahendra. That's weird that the Form Designer puts a limit like that, when it doesn't appear to need to.